# What data has to be used for A/B test of email newsletters to optimize revenue?

Tags: sample-size, ab-test

**My problem**: I have to optimize a newsletter with offers products in an online shop. I have 1,000,000 addresses and two quite similar newsletters that have to be compared. I have read about Chi square and G-test, but what data I have to use?

Sending a newsletter I can count the opening of the mail, the clicking, buying, the price of the products, the sales and every revenue. What should I use?
If I send newsletter A and B to a sample of 20,000 customers, about 5,000 will open the mail, 500 will click, 200 are buying one or more products. Mostly cheap products, but some maybe very expensive.

I want to calculate if A or B will get more revenue if I send A or B to the 1,000,000 customers.

Is the sample size enough? My problem is that for example A can have a 5 % better opening rate, but 20% less clicks, but 15% less buys, but 20% more profit, if maybe 2 customers were buying very expensive products.

Have I to forget the products and prices? Have I to put them in classes? Maybe logarithmic? And then, what statistical hypothesis test would be good for this problem?
How can I calculate a useful sample size?

Comment: I assume that shops are most interested in people *buying* something. Opening mail & clicks are probably only useful if they lead to people buying something (though I can see cases where this would not be true). So, I think it's reasonable to focus on trying to optimize purchases to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for our answer. Sure, the number of purchases is important, but 200 purchases with an average revenue of 10 $ are better than 300 with 5$.

Comment: And even if I only want to optimize the number of purchases, how large has the sample size to be? In normal cases the open rate, the clicks and the purchases have to show a similar behaviour. More openings result in more clicks and purchases. If in my example email A has a 5 % better opening rate, but 20% less clicks, but 15% less buys is this showing that the sample size is too small and the statistic is not valid?
And what have I to test with for example chi²-test: 5.000 openers vs 15.000 non-openers? 200 buyers vs 19.800 non-buyers? 200 buyers with opening vs 4.800 non-buyers with opening?

Comment: To address your first comment above: yes, you want to optimize for revenue (or profit) per set of emails, not per purchase. So if you have revenue/profit information, that's probably ideal.